# How do I insert a new node to an existing XML

Tags: android, xml

I would like to insert a new node into a existent xml file, but The code below inserts all the nodes again.

I do a test if the file exists. If not, I create a new xml file and write the tags. If exists, it also creates the nodes, but the wrong way.

```
//create a new file called "new.xml" in the SD card
File newxmlfile = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/download/teste/audit.xml");

if (newxmlfile.exists()){

    try{
        fileos = new FileOutputStream(newxmlfile, true);
    }catch(FileNotFoundException e){
        Log.e("FileNotFoundException", "can't create FileOutputStream");
    }


} else {                    

    try{
        newxmlfile.createNewFile();
    }catch(IOException e){
        Log.e("IOException", "exception in createNewFile() method");
    }

    try{
        fileos = new FileOutputStream(newxmlfile);
    }catch(FileNotFoundException e){
        Log.e("FileNotFoundException", "can't create FileOutputStream");
    }
}

//we create a XmlSerializer in order to write xml data
XmlSerializer serializer = Xml.newSerializer();
try {
    serializer.setOutput(fileos, "UTF-8");
    serializer.startDocument(null, Boolean.valueOf(true));
    serializer.setFeature("http://xmlpull.org/v1/doc/features.html#indent-output", true);

    serializer.startTag(null, "root");
        serializer.startTag(null, "child1");
        serializer.endTag(null, "child1");

        serializer.startTag(null, "child2");
        serializer.attribute(null, "attribute", "value");
        serializer.endTag(null, "child2");

            serializer.startTag(null, "child3");
        serializer.text("some text inside child3");
        serializer.endTag(null, "child3");                           
    serializer.endTag(null, "root");
    serializer.endDocument();
    serializer.flush();
    fileos.close();

    Context context = getApplicationContext();
    CharSequence text = "Save!";
    int duration = Toast.LENGTH_SHORT;
    Toast toast = Toast.makeText(context, text, duration);
    toast.show();

} catch (Exception e) {
    Log.e("Exception","error occurred while creating xml file");
}
```

The result is this:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' standalone='yes' ?>
<root>
  <child1 />
  <child2 attribute="value" />
  <child3>some text inside child3</child3>
</root><?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' standalone='yes' ?>
<root>
  <child1 />
  <child2 attribute="value" />
  <child3>some text inside child3</child3>
</root>
```

But I want the result like this:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' standalone='yes' ?>
<root>
  <child1 />
  <child2 attribute="value" />
  <child3>some text inside child3</child3>
  <child1 />
  <child2 attribute="value" />
  <child3>some text inside child3</child3>
</root>
```

Thanks!

Comment: So the issue is - another root get created instead of using existing one (in case if file already contains child1-3), right? BTW in the code there's no insertion of child4-6.

Comment: Correct.
I want this: If the document does not exist, it creates the default structure, and then inserts the node.

And if the document exists, insert the new node inside root node , and not repeating the structure `<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' standalone='yes' ?>
<root>"`

Comment: @Wesley: Can u please help me with my similar problem? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21318966/adding-a-node-to-same-xml-file-on-sd-card-under-its-root-tag-in-android

Comment: Iam facing same Problem.Have you got solution for @D'yerMak'er

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like there's not such API in Android. However, You still have the following options to fix the issue:

- Look for some open-source library which provides such ability;
- Do some manual string operations still using `XmlSerializer`, like provided below:

  ```
  private void testXMLFiles() {
      //create a new file called "new.xml" in the SD card
      final File newXmlFile = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/download/teste/audit.xml");
      RandomAccessFile randomAccessFile = null;
      final boolean fileExists = newXmlFile.exists();
      String lastLine = null;

      if (fileExists) {
          try {
              randomAccessFile = new RandomAccessFile(newXmlFile, "rw");
              randomAccessFile.seek(0);

              if (null != randomAccessFile) {
                  final Scanner scanner = new Scanner(newXmlFile);
                  int lastLineOffset = 0;
                  int lastLineLength = 0;

                  while (scanner.hasNextLine()) {
                      // +1 is for end line symbol
                      lastLine = scanner.nextLine();
                      lastLineLength = lastLine.length() + 2;
                      lastLineOffset += lastLineLength;
                  }

                  // don't need last </root> line offset
                  lastLineOffset -= lastLineLength;

                  // got to string before last
                  randomAccessFile.seek(lastLineOffset);
              }
          } catch(FileNotFoundException e) {
              Log.e("FileNotFoundException", "can't create FileOutputStream");
          } catch (IOException e) {
              Log.e("IOException", "Failed to find last line");
          }
      } else {
          try {
              newXmlFile.createNewFile();
          } catch(IOException e) {
              Log.e("IOException", "exception in createNewFile() method");
          }

          try {
              randomAccessFile = new RandomAccessFile(newXmlFile, "rw");
          } catch(FileNotFoundException e) {
              Log.e("FileNotFoundException", "can't create FileOutputStream");
          }
      }

      //we create a XmlSerializer in order to write xml data
      XmlSerializer serializer = Xml.newSerializer();

      if (randomAccessFile == null) {
          return;
      }

      try {
          final StringWriter writer = new StringWriter();

          serializer.setOutput(writer);

          if (!fileExists) {
              serializer.startDocument(null, true);
              serializer.setFeature("http://xmlpull.org/v1/doc/features.html#indent-output", true);
              serializer.startTag(null, "root");
          } else {
              serializer.setFeature("http://xmlpull.org/v1/doc/features.html#indent-output", true);
          }

          serializer.startTag(null, "child1");
          serializer.endTag(null, "child1");

          serializer.startTag(null, "child2");
          serializer.attribute(null, "attribute", "value");
          serializer.endTag(null, "child2");

          serializer.startTag(null, "child3");
          serializer.text("some text inside child3");
          serializer.endTag(null, "child3");

          if (!fileExists) {
              serializer.endTag(null, "root");
          }

          serializer.flush();

          if (lastLine != null) {
              serializer.endDocument();
              writer.append(lastLine);
          }

          // Add \n just for better output in console
          randomAccessFile.writeBytes(writer.toString() + "\n");
          randomAccessFile.close();

          Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Save!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
      } catch (Exception e) {
          Log.e("Exception","error occurred while creating xml file");
          e.printStackTrace();
      }
  }
  ```

Its output after second run is the following (quite similar to what You expect):

```
<?xml version='1.0' standalone='yes' ?>
<root>
  <child1 />
  <child2 attribute="value" />
  <child3>some text inside child3</child3>

<child1 />
<child2 attribute="value" />
<child3>some text inside child3</child3></root>
```

- Store all tags from initial xml (e.g. using [SAXParser](http://developer.android.com/reference/javax/xml/parsers/SAXParser.html) you can read tags, write to new file the same time and apppend new ones at the end using `XMLSerializer`);

Comment: Until the 2º creation, the json file is generated correctly. From the 3º, he inserts the tag <child 3> after last nodes <child 1> and <child 2> and before the end node root.  
`1º node
   <child1 attribute="value"/>
   <child2 attribute="value"/>
   <child3>some text...</ child3>

2º
<child1 attribute="value"/>
<child2 attribute="value" />

3º onwards
<child1 attribute="value"/>
<child2 attribute="value"/>
<child3>some text...</child3><child3>some te...</child3><child3> some ...</child3></root>`
  
But you gave me the way. Now it only adjust the script to generate correctly.

Thanks

Comment: Right, seems new line should be added to have </root> on new line.

Comment: @sandrstar: I have a similar problem like the question above. Could you please help me with my this question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21318966/adding-a-node-to-same-xml-file-on-sd-card-under-its-root-tag-in-android

I would greatly appreciate it.

Comment: @D'yerMak'er will check it.

Comment: Thank you @sandrstar for your reply. Please look into it.

Comment: Ya damn  good. In this way i am able to append data to xml file  but when i retriving data i can read data at first time after appending data iam unable to read data.

Comment: XmlPullParser myparser = xmlFactoryObject.newPullParser();
myparser.setInput(new FileInputStream(tempfile), null);
while (event != XmlPullParser.END_DOCUMENT)
 {

    String name = myparser.getName();

   switch (event) {

 case XmlPullParser.START_TAG:

 if (name.equals("MyTag")) {


  temp3 = myparser.getAttributeValue(null, "Attribute1");temp2 = myparser.getAttributeValue(null, "Attribute2");
                temp1 = myparser.getAttributeValue(null, "Attribute3");
  list1.add(datetemp);list2.add(titletemp);list3.add(datatemp);              

 }
       
           break;

Comment: sry for unable to show proper way..   i am getting null value at                        String name = myparser.getName();

Comment: I opend the xml file in storage i found that the xml file is like this:                                                      <?xml version='1.0' standalone='yes' ?><root>                                                                                                                                       <MyTag  Attribute1="Value 1"    Attribute2="Value 2"  Attribute3="Value 3" /                                                                   Here no closing tag  ithink it is the problem

Comment: <MyTag  Attribute1="Value 1"     Attribute2="Value 2"      Attribute3="Value 3" / ></root>